# Visual Studio 2015 Failing

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I have VS2015  Professional installed and it has started failing from last week and giving "LegacySitePackage failed for package [Image Service Package]" error. I have tried many solution

1) Repair

2) Uninstall - reinstall

3) Uninstall and removing all files which includes registery

4) Deleting files from component folder

5) Uninstall plugging - DevExpress and ApexSql

But of no issue issue still stand as it is [Error in ActivityLog.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4S6eI.png)

Answer (score 1):

First, close all instances of Visual Studio, **rename** the folder or delete everything in:

1. C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0 and
2. C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0
   ,restart Visual Studio

Second, running "devenv /clearcache devenv /updateconfiguration"

Comment: I have tried the steps but issue still persists, I have ever uninstall then removed all the files and then reinstall. But issue remain

Comment: Did you already tried to start VS 2015 in safe mode?"Devenv.exe /SafeMode" https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241278.aspx In addition, try to restore Visual Studio packages with below command.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms241276.aspx